# Logic: Proofs in normal form

Tags: logic

Go to the "Articles" section of Neil Tennant's site http://people.cohums.ohio-state.edu/tennant9/
In the second and third paragraphs of page 18 of the fourth article down ('Inferentialism, Logicism, Harmony, and a Counterpoint') Tennant says that reduction procedures may not explicate balance in those proof systems where proofs are required to be in normal form, since "the pre-images for the reduction procedure will not be proofs; and, often, the reducts will not be, either."

(1) What is a proof in normal form?
(2) Why require of a proof system that its proofs be in normal form? (What advantages are there to this requirement)
(3) What does Tennant mean by his statement that "the pre-images (?) for the reduction procedure will not be proofs; and, often, the reducts will not be, either"?

Comment: The link doesn't take us to a paper of Tennant's but to the front page of his website.

Comment: It is the fourth article down in the "Articles" section of Tennant's site ('Inferentialism, Logicism, Harmony, and a Counterpoint').

Answer (score 2):

(i) "Normal form" (in a natural deduction setting) means normal form in the standard proof theoretic sense from Gentzen/Prawitz (i.e., roughly, lacking detours where we e.g. use $A$ and a side premiss to prove $A \land B$ and then use $A \land B$ to prove $A$). Consult a standard proof-theory text on normalisation of natural deduction proofs. [Tennant's own elementary book *Natural Logic* is now available freely from his website, Prawitz's book is cheaply available.]

(ii) It is natural to prefer proofs without unnecessary detours (hence the interest in meta-proofs that proofs in certain systems are normalizable). So it is indeed also of interest to consider systems where proofs are actually already required to be in normal form.

(iii) In such systems where all proofs are already in normal form there aren't "reduction procedures" taking us from proofs with detours to proofs with fewer detours (which, iterated, eventually normalise a proof). That's why, as Tennant says, "a [general] proposal that one appeal to reduction procedures" to explain some phenomenon might be problematic, in not applying to these proof systems where all proofs are, perforce, already normal. (But he goes on to say more about what might play the explanatory role for such systems.)